# Python, package exists on PyPi but cant install it via pip

Tags: python, pip, pypi

The package `PyAudioWPatch` is shown as available on PyPi with a big old green check mark.
https://pypi.org/project/PyAudioWPatch/

However when I try to install it, I am getting the following error:

```
% pip install PyAudioWPatch                                                                    

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyAudioWPatch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyAudioWPatch
```

For context:

```
% python -V; pip -V
Python 3.9.13
pip 22.3.1 from /Users/petertoth/Documents/Desktop_record_sum/py/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The project has only wheels for Windows, and your system is not Windows, hence the error.

And I should assume that to be *by design*, because it declares to be a *PortAudio fork with WASAPI loopback support*. As WASAPI is a Windows thing, it does not make sense to install it on a non Windows system.

IMHO, you'd better install the original project. If you really want this one, then you should try to get it from [GitHub](https://github.com/s0d3s/PyAudioWPatch)

Comment: That is true, I got confused from the docs mentioning `darwin`: <https://github.com/s0d3s/PyAudioWPatch/blob/master/examples/origin_examples/record.py#L17>